# Customizing the views for the picker view with viewForRow. Can't seem to set view heigh properly

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to customize the pickerview row views with :

```
pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
```

The problem I'm having is that my view which is loaded from a nib/xib does not get the correct row size.

Here is my code :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    if let reuseView = view as? ImageTypePickerView {
        return reuseView
    } else {
        let myRowView = ImageTypePickerReusableView()
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: component)

        if let myUnitImageType = self.frc?.object(at: indexPath) as? UnitImageType {
            let image = UIImage(data: myUnitImageType.imageData! as Data)
            myRowView.typeImage.image = image
            myRowView.typeLabel.text = myUnitImageType.name
            myRowView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:100, height: 108)

        }
        return myRowView
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to also use? :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 108
}
```

? ? ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get rid of those selected row lines above and below my view? I tried to set self.showsSelectionIndicator to false and I still see the bars/lines

Comment: Last question, promisse!  Would anyone recommend using a collectionviewcontroller with a customized layouy instead of trying to customized this old but useful uipickerview control?

Comment: Comments are not for asking more questions. And yes, you need to implement the height delegate method.